# How do I fix ubuntu not booting after right after rebooting after installation?

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu runs fine, and sometimes even reboots completely ok. But every once in a while when I reboot it boots and says that it is going to attempt to run in low graphics mode in Ubuntu 16.0.4. Then it says it is scanning sda1 or something, it is really strange. I have no idea what causes this. I have an Alienware 14 laptop. Has anybody experienced the same thing?

Comment: You can check by installing [GDM](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/gdm).

Comment: What's on sda1? Do you dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu? Please post a screenshot of gparted for your sda drive. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 0):

I guess its something wrong with your bootloader...
Did you do custom partitioning?

This link should help you.
http://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/